# BTEQ Keywords in Snowflake SnowSQL

Tags: teradata, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

In Teradata BTEQ we have various commands like below,

.IF ERRORCODE<>0 QUIT 1;
.GOTO
.LABEL
.IF ACTIVITYCOUNT=0 QUIT 1;

Do we have anything similar in SnowSQL?

Note: Coverting BTEQ's to SnowSQL Scripts

Comment: Not exactly, but you can leverage several functionalities that might give you same result, like for example [JavaScript UDF](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/udf-js.html)

Comment: You'd probably want to use a shell script which uses the SnowSQL tool to so something like this.